# Why is the requests module not installed according to the google-auth library?

Tags: python, python-requests, google-calendar-api, google-auth-library

I'm using the Google Calendar API to fetch some events and I'm using a venv to house all the packages required, and I've run into a simple problem: `google.auth.transport.requests` can't function correctly, citing the `requests` package is not installed.

### Code and error:

---

The problem can be observed using a single line of code:

```
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
```

The following error is dumped to the console from [`google.auth.transport.requests`](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/google/auth/transport/requests.html) (at the bottom of two tracebacks):

```
File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
ImportError: The requests library is not installed, please install the requests package to use the requests transport.
```

### Failed attempts

---

1. Deleting and remaking the venv.
2. Install modules with --no-cache-dir and --ignore-installed.

### Information

---

1. Executing `import requests` or `from google.auth.transport.requests import Request` from the console from `env\Scripts\python` works without problem.
2. The same lines when put in a file `temp.py` when placed inside the following directories execute in the following manner:

   - `AutoMate\`: Safe
   - `AutoMate\src\`: Safe
   - `AutoMate\src\sources\`: Error
   - `AutoMate\src\sources\temp\`: Safe (sources\temp only made for debugging)
   - `AutoMate\src\sources\util\`: Safe.

Note: All tests here and below have been ran from AutoMate\ using `env\Scripts\python` and `env\Scripts\pip`.

3. None of the google auth modules have been installed in the pip outside of the venv.
4. The project structure is as follows:

```
AutoMate
|   temp.py
├───env
│   ├───Include
│   ├───Lib
│   └───Scripts
└───src
    │   AutoMate.pyw
    │
    └───sources
        │   calendar.py --> Problematic file
        │   whatsapp.py
        │   __init__.py
        │  
        └───util
```

5. Output of `env\Scripts\pip list`:

```
Package                  Version
------------------------ ---------
cachetools               4.2.1
certifi                  2020.12.5
chardet                  4.0.0
google-api-core          1.26.1
google-api-python-client 2.0.2
google-auth              1.27.1
google-auth-httplib2     0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib     0.4.3
googleapis-common-protos 1.53.0
httplib2                 0.19.0
idna                     2.10
oauthlib                 3.1.0
packaging                20.9
pip                      21.0.1
protobuf                 3.15.5
pyasn1                   0.4.8
pyasn1-modules           0.2.8
pyparsing                2.4.7
pytz                     2021.1
requests                 2.25.1
requests-oauthlib        1.3.0
rsa                      4.7.2
selenium                 3.141.0
setuptools               49.2.1
six                      1.15.0
uritemplate              3.0.1
urllib3                  1.26.3
```

Answer (score 4):

### Solution

---

Any file that uses `google.auth.transport.requests` must not have **any** file named exactly `calendar.py`** in the same directory as itself.
Any* other filename works, even `calendar.python` and `Calendar.py`.

** On testing it seems like `requests.py` and `datetime.py` are also some invalid names, while `math.py` and `time.py` seem to work fine, maybe the invalid names are used internally? Need further knowledge.

### Reason

---

It looks like some there's some internal interference to me, I'm hoping someone will respond with the reason to this problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is a try-except block within `google.auth.transport.requests` while importing `requests` package, which defaults to that error message even if the package was already installed. [Code](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-python/blob/main/google/auth/transport/requests.py#L25)

Trying to import requests directly in REPL revealed that there was in issue with `from collections import Mapping` (I was using Python v3.10 at the time). As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70557518/14049187), downgrading my Python version and creating a new venv helped me with this problem.