# ImportError: cannot import name '...' from 'collections' using Python 3.10

Tags: python, importerror, python-3.10, python-collections

I am trying to run my program which uses various dependencies, but since upgrading to Python 3.10 this does not work anymore.
When I run "python3" in the terminal and from there import my dependencies I get an error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

This seems to be a general problem, but here is the traceback of my specific case:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/mk/Flasktut/app.py", line 2, in <module>
  from flask import Flask, render_template
 File "/Users/mk/Flasktut/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
  from jinja2 import escape
 File "/Users/mk/Flasktut/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
  from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template
 File "/Users/mk/Flasktut/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 16, in <module>
  from jinja2.defaults import BLOCK_START_STRING, \
 File "/Users/mk/Flasktut/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/defaults.py", line 32, in <module>
  from jinja2.tests import TESTS as DEFAULT_TESTS
 File "/Users/mk/Flasktut/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jinja2/tests.py", line 13, in <module>
  from collections import Mapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

Comment: [What’s New In Python 3.10: `collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#collections-abc). Mitra, when you encounter an issue with a standard library that used to work in previous versions, faster than poking around the internals is to check the whatsnew for that and previous versions.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Change:

```
from collections import Mapping
```

to

```
from collections.abc import Mapping
```

Comment: Go to test.py: and then from inside test.py go to the line "from collections import Mapping" and change it to "from collections.abc import Mapping"

Comment: Where is test.py?

Comment: This doesn't help when importing requests, which uses Mapping.

Comment: @sspence65 In this case you must update `requests` to a version which supports your Python version.

Comment: It does not help with 3.10.9 version of python, seems I need to downgrade version of python =>  Requires: Python >=3.7 (requests official web page)

Comment: not an ideal solution, gotta fix massive file if the collections package has changed public variables

Answer (score 38):

This is caused by a change in the `collections` interface starting with Python 3.10. As far as I can see there are three options to mitigate this issue so far:

- If the error occurs in a third-party library, try to update this library first (`pip install <package> --upgrade`).
- Revert to Python 3.9.
- Patch the code manually.

  For patching the `ImportError`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/69727802/13994294.

Answer (score 15):

You need to import from the new `abc` module inside of `collections` for later versions of Python.

If you need to make your code backwards compatible with older versions of Python, you can use this:

```
try:
    from collections.abc import Mapping
except ImportError:
    from collections import Mapping
```

Answer (score 7):

#### Cause of the error

If you tried the import in Python 3.9.x, it becomes clear:

```
Python 3.9.10 (main, Jan 15 2022, 11:40:53)
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from collections import Mapping
<stdin>:1: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.10 it will stop working
```

It clearly mentions that **in 3.10 it will stop working**. So to use please change the version to Python 3.9 or below.
If you are using *pipenv* to manage your virtual-environment, then the steps could be as follow:

```
$ pipenv --rm        # to remove the virtual env
$ exit               # to exit the virtual env
$ vim Pipfile        # here change the version to '3.9' by replacing '3.10'
$ pipenv shell       # this will create a virtual env with 3.9
$ pipenv install     # to install the requirements
```

We just switched from Python 3.10 to Python 3.9, which supports the code for now.

Answer (score 4):

Use older version of python (eg 3.8)

Comment: 3.9.7 also works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I added

```
from collections.abc import Mapping
from collections.abc import MutableMapping
from collections.abc import Sequence
```

in

"C:\Users\natha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\collections_*init*_.py"

Answer (score 0):

A cause of this problem can be an outdated package

In my case updating  [PyJWT](https://pypi.org/project/PyJWT/) on requirements.txt to the latest version fixed the issue

Answer (score -3):

That's about python version.
in most time python 3.10 have this problems.

You can solve this problem with use python 3.9 or 3.8 version.
or
if error from packages like python-docx or other packages about MS you can probably solve it by using pipwin.

Answer (score -3):

Same here, but I resolved the problem with:

```
pip3 list --outdated --format=freeze | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1 | xargs -n1 pip3 install -U
```

This wi

Comment: -1 Your answer is not finished, when I try to run it I get the following error: `ERROR: List format 'freeze' can not be used with the --outdated option.`

Answer (score -3):

Recommend using a previous version of python (e.g 3.8 pr 3.9) in a virtualenv rather than reverting your python on your root system.

```
virtualenv --python="/YOUR PATH/python3.9" "name of your env"
```

Comment: It was tried in a virtual environment but didn't work.

Answer (score -5):

In my environment the problem was solved using bug fix Python version 3.10.2

Answer (score -5):

Just update to **requests 2.27.1** and **python 3.10.2** or later, and the problem will be fixed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have `requests 2.27.1` and `python 3.10.4` and I still get the error

Comment: Go to test.py: and then from inside the test.py go to the line "from collections import Mapping" and change it to "from collections.abc import Mapping"