# doing course on udemy and I'm at the point of getting "token" but can't run the server

Tags: python, rest

because, I have this trouble. I'm using python3.10.

```
(venv) alexeykhorishko@Alexeys-MacBook-Pro code % python3 app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alexeykhorishko/Desktop/flaskapp/code/app.py", line 3, in <module>
    from flask_jwt import JWT, JWT_required
  File "/Users/alexeykhorishko/Desktop/flaskapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask_jwt/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    import jwt
  File "/Users/alexeykhorishko/Desktop/flaskapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jwt/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from .api_jwt import (
  File "/Users/alexeykhorishko/Desktop/flaskapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jwt/api_jwt.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .api_jws import PyJWS
  File "/Users/alexeykhorishko/Desktop/flaskapp/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/jwt/api_jws.py", line 5, in <module>
    from collections import Mapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

Comment: Please do some bare-minimum research before posting here, in accordance with [ask]. This is a duplicate of [in VS Code ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69381312/in-vs-code-importerror-cannot-import-name-mapping-from-collections)

Comment: could now find the solution. Please help me out

Comment: I read it and tried to implement in my code. but has worked at all

Comment: *has not worked

Comment: Using or importing the ABCs from `collections` instead of from `collections.abc` has been deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.10 it stopped working.

Comment: So your JWT library is broken.