# undetected-chromedriver import is unsuccessful. ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections'

Tags: python, python-3.x, undetected-chromedriver

I tried to import undetected_chromedriver

```
import undetected-chromedriver.v2 as uc

driver = uc.Chrome()

resp = driver.get("https://google.com")
```

Running above code throws following error.

```
File "C:\Users\Narmu\Desktop\Python_Workspace_Master\venv\lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\cdp.py"

from collections import Mapping, Sequence
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections'
```

I search for about **collections** packages but it is not available in package list

I found a suggestion from [in VS Code ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69381312/in-vs-code-importerror-cannot-import-name-mapping-from-collections)?.

But **collections.abc** also not available in package list.

I use python verion 3.10.

To make this work, kindly suggest me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer as of 12/11/2021: Don't use Python 3.10. It has bug here and there with undetected_chromedriver package.

I downgraded to 3.7.9 and now all running perfectly fine. You may try other Python version though.