# Pip is not working anymore after --force-reinstall pip==18.1

Tags: python, linux, pip, fedora

I have a problem, I was attempting to install a module in python which I couldn't install due to some error, so I found a post where it was suggested to run the following command: `python -m pip install --force-reinstall pip==18.1`

Now if I try to install a module, or even if I type pip --version, I get :

```
[User@fedora-laptop ~]$ pip install pandas

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/home/User/.local/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>

from pip._internal import main

File "/home/User/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>

from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete

File "/home/User/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module>

from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser

File "/home/User/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 12, in <module>

from pip._internal.commands import (

File "/home/User/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>

from pip._internal.commands.completion import CompletionCommand

File "/home/User/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/completion.py", line 6, in <module>

from pip._internal.cli.base_command import Command

File "/home/User/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 23, in <module>

from pip._internal.index import PackageFinder

File "/home/User/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_internal/index.py", line 14, in <module>

from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests, six

File "/home/User/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>

from .html5parser import HTMLParser, parse, parseFragment

File "/home/User/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/html5parser.py", line 8, in <module>

from . import _tokenizer

File "/home/User/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/_tokenizer.py", line 16, in <module>

from ._trie import Trie

File "/home/User/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/_trie/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>

from .py import Trie as PyTrie

File "/home/User/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/_trie/py.py", line 6, in <module>

from ._base import Trie as ABCTrie

File "/home/User/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/_trie/_base.py", line 3, in <module>

from collections import Mapping

ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib64/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

Os: Linux Fedora

Python version: Python 3.10.2

Comment: Please check below answer, especially accepted solution 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69381312/in-vs-code-importerror-cannot-import-name-mapping-from-collections

Comment: @PankajK Thank you it solved my problem:
I edited the file /home/User/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/_trie/_base.py as suggested by the link you provided me.

Then I ran pip install --upgrade pip --user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using the solution provided by: [in VS Code ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69381312/in-vs-code-importerror-cannot-import-name-mapping-from-collections):
I edited the file /home/User/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/html5lib/_trie/_base.py. Then, in a terminal, I ran pip install --upgrade pip --user