# Error when trying to launch TuxCut (netcut analogue for ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu

Currently I am trying to launch TuxCut (a NetCut analogue for ubuntu) and I am facing this error:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognomeproxy.so: undefined symbol: g_task_set_name
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognomeproxy.so
/tmp/_MEI4s6nWH/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.29' not found (required by /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libproxy.so.1)
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiolibproxy.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so: undefined symbol: g_task_set_name
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgioremote-volume-monitor.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognutls.so: undefined symbol: g_byte_array_steal
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgiognutls.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gvfs/libgvfscommon.so: undefined symbol: g_task_set_name
Failed to load module: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gio/modules/libgvfsdbus.so

(tuxcut:6267): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: 23:29:51.458: Settings schema 'org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings' does not contain a key named 'antialiasing'
/usr/bin/tuxcut: line 2:  6266 Trace/breakpoint trap   (core dumped) /opt/tuxcut/tuxcut
```

[first screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNKjZ.png)

I am a new to ubuntu, so sorry if the answer is obvious. ;/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Ubuntu 22.04 (x86_64)

- Won't run.  I tried fixing each error by hand, but more cropped up.  For example, I found a workaround for the `antialiasing` error by un-deprecating it from the `org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings.gschema.xml` glib-compile-schemas`but then it starts to crash on a "Unrecognized image file format" for a`.png` that exists on the system.  This application is not compatible with Ubuntu 22.04.

#### Ubuntu 16.04 (x86_64)

- Won't run.  Installs but complains about a missing library.  After attempting to install it, starting `tuxcut` crashes the machine.

#### Building from source

After installing [`wxPython`](https://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20install%20wxPython) (in my case on ARM64, this was through a series of [very tedious errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69727802/3196753), and dependencies) the daemon (command line, not the GUI) of TuxCut that you can [Run From Source](https://github.com/a-atalla/tuxcut#run-from-source) starts, but with warnings on Ubuntu 22.04.

```
$ sudo python server/tuxcutd.py 
INFO:apscheduler.scheduler:Scheduler started
INFO:apscheduler.scheduler:Added job "ARP Spoofing the victim list" to job store "default"
INFO:apscheduler.scheduler:Scheduler started
INFO:apscheduler.scheduler:Added job "ARP Spoofing the victim list" to job store "default"
Bottle v0.12.23 server starting up (using WSGIRefServer())...
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8013/
Hit Ctrl-C to quit.

INFO:apscheduler.executors.default:Running job "ARP Spoofing the victim list (trigger: interval[0:00:01], next run at: 2022-09-23 02:07:18 EDT)" (scheduled at 2022-09-23 02:07:18.933925-04:00)
INFO:apscheduler.executors.default:Job "ARP Spoofing the victim list (trigger: interval[0:00:01], next run at: 2022-09-23 02:07:18 EDT)" executed successfully
INFO:apscheduler.executors.default:Running job "ARP Spoofing the victim list (trigger: interval[0:00:01], next run at: 2022-09-23 02:07:19 EDT)" (scheduled at 2022-09-23 02:07:19.065895-04:00)
...
```

The errors in Ubuntu 22.04 suggest TuxCut is binary incompatible with some libraries on newer Ubuntu versions.  The source [hasn't received any major updates in 4 years](https://github.com/a-atalla/tuxcut/commits/master), so this does not come as a surprise.

If you're ok building from source, you should be able to get the daemon started (the daemon might run from the `.deb` file, but my machine isn't Intel so I can't test it), however due to the lack of project activity, it may make sense to look into alternatives for the long-term, especially if you expect the graphical interface to work.

> I am a new to ubuntu, so sorry if the answer is obvious. ;/

What's not obvious on Linux in general is that many great software projects are no longer maintained and that many commercial software projects are not available.  Sometimes, if you're lucky, you can get them working by searching error message, but this takes time.  In my case, getting this app to run (with warnings and no GUI) took over ~~two~~ three hours due to some very obscure Python error messages, trying different Ubuntu versions and the long build time of wxPython on my system.

The worst part about this "build from source" process is that core Python packages are simply broken (or perhaps incompatible with the `pip` versions?), so I had to edit quite a few python files just to get the daemon started and the `dependencies.txt` simply doesn't work for my Python version (3.10), so it really depends how far down the rabbit hole you want to go.

Alternately, you may consider finding the last working operating system that this package worked on and try that... [if its too old, it may be missing important security updates](https://ubuntu.com/about/release-cycle) so please do this at your own risk.