# Pip isn't working after downgrading to version 18

Tags: python, macos, terminal, pip

I downgraded Pip from the most recent version using `sudo python -m pip install pip==18.0 --upgrade`, and now I am receiving the following error when running pip/pip3, including when trying to re-upgrade it using `pip3 install --upgrade pip`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 5, in \<module\>
from pip.\_internal import main
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/\_internal/__init__.py", line 42, in \<module\>
from pip.\_internal import cmdoptions
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/\_internal/cmdoptions.py", line 16, in \<module\>
from pip.\_internal.index import (
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/\_internal/index.py", line 14, in \<module\>
from pip.\_vendor import html5lib, requests, six
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/\_vendor/html5lib/__init__.py", line 25, in \<module\>
from .html5parser import HTMLParser, parse, parseFragment
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/\_vendor/html5lib/html5parser.py", line 8, in \<module\>
from . import \_tokenizer
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/\_vendor/html5lib/\_tokenizer.py", line 16, in \<module\>
from .\_trie import Trie
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/\_vendor/html5lib/\_trie/__init__.py", line 3, in \<module\>
from .py import Trie as PyTrie
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/\_vendor/html5lib/\_trie/py.py", line 6, in \<module\>
from .\_base import Trie as ABCTrie
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/\_vendor/html5lib/\_trie/\_base.py", line 3, in \<module\>
from collections import Mapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)
```

Comment: I see a close vote on this as "not about programming", even though the description of that close reason says "Use this close reason if the question is not about a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or **software tools primarily used by programmers.**" `pip` is a software tool primarily used by programmers, so that close reason makes no sense here. Hopefully no one else votes to close this for that reason.

Comment: Why did you downgrade in the first place? pip 18 is quite old.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there's a specific reason you installed pip 18.0 as it looks incompatible with Python 3.10. It looks like [in Python 3.10](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69727802/11659881) `collections.Mapping` moved to `collections.abc.Mapping`. I would suggest just completely uninstalling pip and reinstalling, without using pip to do so.

In general, you should try to use the latest version of pip.

Comment: Thanks so much! How should I go about completely uninstalling/reinstalling without pip?