# IBM® Cloud Private-CE Python ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections'

Tags: python

I am trying to install IBM Cloud Private-CE as per:

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-private/3.1.2?topic=installing-cloud-private-cloud-native-enterprise-community-editions

on Fedora 37 with:

[root@bc1 ~]# python --version
Python 3.11.1

[root@bc1 ~]# pip --version
pip 22.2.2 from /usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)

and am getting error from:

[root@bc1 cluster]# podman run --net=host -t -e LICENSE=accept -v /opt/ibm-cloud-private-3.1.2/cluster:/installer/cluster:Z ibmcom/icp-inception:3.1.2 check

```
  File "/tmp/ansible_3uadhnbq/ansible_module_setup.py", line 125, in <module>
    from ansible.module_utils.basic import AnsibleModule
  File "/tmp/ansible_3uadhnbq/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/basic.py", line 83, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib64/python3.11/collections/__init__.py)
```

[in VS Code ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69381312/in-vs-code-importerror-cannot-import-name-mapping-from-collections)

suggests: change:

from collections import Mapping

to

from collections.abc import Mapping

the referencing Python file seems to be within their icp-inception:3.1.2 container,

might anyone know about this problem?

Comment: You're trying to run code that was written for an earlier version of Python.  `Mapping` and lots of similar classes were added to `collections.abc` in 3.3, and removed from `collections` in 3.9.

Comment: I re-tried running a more recent: 

    IBM Cloud Private CE 3.2.0  via  Python3.8

which stalled at:

TASK [network-check : Checking for the network pre-check file]
fatal: [192.168.1.21 -> localhost]: FAILED! => changed=false

MODULE FAILURE 


I do not know how to interpret the (Python3.8 MODULE?) "network-check" error message;

perhaps Python3.8 was not able to find a some link for: [192.168.1.21 -> localhost]?

Python 3.8 seemed to be looking for some file,
however I believe that perhaps links are considered as such?

Comment: not sure if a previous: "[WARNING]" has any significance:

TASK [Gathering Facts] ********
 [WARNING]: Module invocation had junk after the JSON data: AttributeError("module 'platform' has no attribute 'dist'")


I was not able to find anything about such error in 
    Chapter 8 "Troubleshooting" in the 
    "IBM Cloud Private System Administrators Guide"


might anyone be able to suggest something?

Comment: I've posted more complete error logs at:

http://synthnetics.com/test/PrivateCloud/IBM-Private-Cloud-CE-3.2.0-module-platform-dist-error.html

Comment: install command for container: ibmcom/icp-inception:3.2.0

also results in error:

TASK [Creating check password script] 
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! =>
  msg: |-
    Failed to get information on remote file (/tmp/check-password-script): /bin/bash: /usr/bin/python3.8: No such file or directory

Comment: more complete /tmp/check-password-script error logs posted at:

http://synthnetics.com/test/PrivateCloud/IBM-Cloud-Private-CE-3.2.0-check-password_script.html