# Problem with 'Mapping' from 'collections' when i want to import gensim package in G Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, environment, gensim, lda

Working on my LDA project and gensim doesn't want to load due to Mapping problem from Collections. It used to work fine for a weeks and now i have a problem.

I'm working on my little LDA project and my colab notebook worked great all time. But today it failed to load dependecies.

```
#Upgrade Gensim + Dependecies
!pip install --upgrade gensim==3.8
from collections.abc import Mapping
import gensim
import gensim.corpora as corpora
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess
from gensim.models.wrappers import LdaMallet
from gensim.models.coherencemodel import CoherenceModel
from gensim import similarities
import pandas as pd
import os.path
import re
import glob
```

Error is:

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/
Collecting gensim==3.8
  Downloading gensim-3.8.0.tar.gz (23.4 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 23.4/23.4 MB 28.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from gensim==3.8) (1.22.4)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.18.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from gensim==3.8) (1.10.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from gensim==3.8) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: smart_open>=1.7.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from gensim==3.8) (6.3.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: gensim
  Building wheel for gensim (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for gensim: filename=gensim-3.8.0-cp310-cp310-linux_x86_64.whl size=24954719 sha256=7c9499f43617a6b8f5d427607ac23e62e34e4377724de0d20cf9018c92a1fb8b
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/01/ab/bf/07d4e3462e9f8d17d98c2fb5e870d7e9934c8482a32fc3ef41
Successfully built gensim
Installing collected packages: gensim
  Attempting uninstall: gensim
    Found existing installation: gensim 4.3.1
    Uninstalling gensim-4.3.1:
      Successfully uninstalled gensim-4.3.1
Successfully installed gensim-3.8.0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f6ba8aee087e> in <cell line: 4>()
      2 get_ipython().system('pip install --upgrade gensim==3.8')
      3 from collections.abc import Mapping
----> 4 import gensim
      5 import gensim.corpora as corpora
      6 from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/gensim/corpora/dictionary.py in <module>
      9 from __future__ import with_statement
     10 
---> 11 from collections import Mapping, defaultdict
     12 import sys
     13 import logging

ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (/usr/lib/python3.10/collections/__init__.py)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the
"Open Examples" button below.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Also mb useful

```
!python --version
Python 3.10.11
```

```
!pip list
Package                       Version
----------------------------- --------------------
absl-py                       1.4.0
alabaster                     0.7.13
albumentations                1.2.1
altair                        4.2.2
anyio                         3.6.2
appdirs                       1.4.4
argon2-cffi                   21.3.0
argon2-cffi-bindings          21.2.0
arviz                         0.15.1
astropy                       5.2.2
astunparse                    1.6.3
attrs                         23.1.0
audioread                     3.0.0
autograd                      1.5
Babel                         2.12.1
backcall                      0.2.0
beautifulsoup4                4.11.2
bleach                        6.0.0
blis                          0.7.9
blosc2                        2.0.0
bokeh                         2.4.3
branca                        0.6.0
CacheControl                  0.12.11
cached-property               1.5.2
cachetools                    5.3.0
catalogue                     2.0.8
certifi                       2022.12.7
cffi                          1.15.1
chardet                       4.0.0
charset-normalizer            2.0.12
chex                          0.1.7
click                         8.1.3
cloudpickle                   2.2.1
cmake                         3.25.2
cmdstanpy                     1.1.0
colorcet                      3.0.1
colorlover                    0.3.0
community                     1.0.0b1
confection                    0.0.4
cons                          0.4.5
contextlib2                   0.6.0.post1
contourpy                     1.0.7
convertdate                   2.4.0
cryptography                  40.0.2
cufflinks                     0.17.3
cvxopt                        1.3.0
cvxpy                         1.3.1
cycler                        0.11.0
cymem                         2.0.7
Cython                        0.29.34
dask                          2022.12.1
datascience                   0.17.6
db-dtypes                     1.1.1
dbus-python                   1.2.16
debugpy                       1.6.6
decorator                     4.4.2
defusedxml                    0.7.1
distributed                   2022.12.1
dlib                          19.24.1
dm-tree                       0.1.8
docutils                      0.16
dopamine-rl                   4.0.6
duckdb                        0.7.1
earthengine-api               0.1.350
easydict                      1.10
ecos                          2.0.12
editdistance                  0.6.2
en-core-web-sm                3.5.0
entrypoints                   0.4
ephem                         4.1.4
et-xmlfile                    1.1.0
etils                         1.2.0
etuples                       0.3.8
exceptiongroup                1.1.1
fastai                        2.7.12
fastcore                      1.5.29
fastdownload                  0.0.7
fastjsonschema                2.16.3
fastprogress                  1.0.3
fastrlock                     0.8.1
filelock                      3.12.0
firebase-admin                5.3.0
Flask                         2.2.4
flatbuffers                   23.3.3
flax                          0.6.9
folium                        0.14.0
fonttools                     4.39.3
frozendict                    2.3.7
fsspec                        2023.4.0
future                        0.18.3
gast                          0.4.0
GDAL                          3.3.2
gdown                         4.6.6
gensim                        3.8.0
geographiclib                 2.0
geopy                         2.3.0
gin-config                    0.5.0
glob2                         0.7
google                        2.0.3
google-api-core               2.11.0
google-api-python-client      2.84.0
google-auth                   2.17.3
google-auth-httplib2          0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib          1.0.0
google-cloud-bigquery         3.9.0
google-cloud-bigquery-storage 2.19.1
google-cloud-core             2.3.2
google-cloud-datastore        2.15.1
google-cloud-firestore        2.11.0
google-cloud-language         2.9.1
google-cloud-storage          2.8.0
google-cloud-translate        3.11.1
google-colab                  1.0.0
google-crc32c                 1.5.0
google-pasta                  0.2.0
google-resumable-media        2.5.0
googleapis-common-protos      1.59.0
googledrivedownloader         0.4
graphviz                      0.20.1
greenlet                      2.0.2
grpcio                        1.54.0
grpcio-status                 1.48.2
gspread                       3.4.2
gspread-dataframe             3.0.8
gym                           0.25.2
gym-notices                   0.0.8
h5netcdf                      1.1.0
h5py                          3.8.0
hijri-converter               2.3.1
holidays                      0.23
holoviews                     1.15.4
html5lib                      1.1
httpimport                    1.3.0
httplib2                      0.21.0
humanize                      4.6.0
hyperopt                      0.2.7
idna                          3.4
imageio                       2.25.1
imageio-ffmpeg                0.4.8
imagesize                     1.4.1
imbalanced-learn              0.10.1
imgaug                        0.4.0
importlib-metadata            6.6.0
importlib-resources           5.12.0
imutils                       0.5.4
inflect                       6.0.4
iniconfig                     2.0.0
intel-openmp                  2023.1.0
ipykernel                     5.5.6
ipython                       7.34.0
ipython-genutils              0.2.0
ipython-sql                   0.4.1
ipywidgets                    7.7.1
itsdangerous                  2.1.2
jax                           0.4.8
jaxlib                        0.4.7+cuda11.cudnn86
jieba                         0.42.1
Jinja2                        3.1.2
joblib                        1.2.0
jsonpickle                    3.0.1
jsonschema                    4.3.3
jupyter-client                6.1.12
jupyter-console               6.1.0
jupyter_core                  5.3.0
jupyter-server                1.24.0
jupyterlab-pygments           0.2.2
jupyterlab-widgets            3.0.7
kaggle                        1.5.13
keras                         2.12.0
keras-vis                     0.4.1
kiwisolver                    1.4.4
korean-lunar-calendar         0.3.1
langcodes                     3.3.0
lazy_loader                   0.2
libclang                      16.0.0
librosa                       0.10.0.post2
lightgbm                      3.3.5
lit                           16.0.2
llvmlite                      0.39.1
locket                        1.0.0
logical-unification           0.4.5
LunarCalendar                 0.0.9
lxml                          4.9.2
Markdown                      3.4.3
markdown-it-py                2.2.0
MarkupSafe                    2.1.2
matplotlib                    3.7.1
matplotlib-inline             0.1.6
matplotlib-venn               0.11.9
mdurl                         0.1.2
miniKanren                    1.0.3
missingno                     0.5.2
mistune                       0.8.4
mizani                        0.8.1
mkl                           2019.0
ml-dtypes                     0.1.0
mlxtend                       0.14.0
more-itertools                9.1.0
moviepy                       1.0.3
mpmath                        1.3.0
msgpack                       1.0.5
multipledispatch              0.6.0
multitasking                  0.0.11
murmurhash                    1.0.9
music21                       8.1.0
natsort                       8.3.1
nbclient                      0.7.4
nbconvert                     6.5.4
nbformat                      5.8.0
nest-asyncio                  1.5.6
networkx                      3.1
nibabel                       3.0.2
nltk                          3.8.1
notebook                      6.4.8
numba                         0.56.4
numexpr                       2.8.4
numpy                         1.22.4
oauth2client                  4.1.3
oauthlib                      3.2.2
opencv-contrib-python         4.7.0.72
opencv-python                 4.7.0.72
opencv-python-headless        4.7.0.72
openpyxl                      3.0.10
opt-einsum                    3.3.0
optax                         0.1.5
orbax-checkpoint              0.2.1
osqp                          0.6.2.post8
packaging                     23.1
palettable                    3.3.3
pandas                        1.5.3
pandas-datareader             0.10.0
pandas-gbq                    0.17.9
pandocfilters                 1.5.0
panel                         0.14.4
param                         1.13.0
parso                         0.8.3
partd                         1.4.0
pathlib                       1.0.1
pathy                         0.10.1
patsy                         0.5.3
pep517                        0.13.0
pexpect                       4.8.0
pickleshare                   0.7.5
Pillow                        8.4.0
pip                           23.0.1
pip-tools                     6.6.2
platformdirs                  3.3.0
plotly                        5.13.1
plotnine                      0.10.1
pluggy                        1.0.0
polars                        0.17.3
pooch                         1.6.0
portpicker                    1.3.9
prefetch-generator            1.0.3
preshed                       3.0.8
prettytable                   0.7.2
proglog                       0.1.10
progressbar2                  4.2.0
prometheus-client             0.16.0
promise                       2.3
prompt-toolkit                3.0.38
prophet                       1.1.2
proto-plus                    1.22.2
protobuf                      3.20.3
psutil                        5.9.5
psycopg2                      2.9.6
ptyprocess                    0.7.0
py-cpuinfo                    9.0.0
py4j                          0.10.9.7
pyarrow                       9.0.0
pyasn1                        0.5.0
pyasn1-modules                0.3.0
pycocotools                   2.0.6
pycparser                     2.21
pyct                          0.5.0
pydantic                      1.10.7
pydata-google-auth            1.7.0
pydot                         1.4.2
pydot-ng                      2.0.0
pydotplus                     2.0.2
PyDrive                       1.3.1
pyerfa                        2.0.0.3
pygame                        2.3.0
Pygments                      2.14.0
PyGObject                     3.36.0
pymc                          5.1.2
PyMeeus                       0.5.12
pymystem3                     0.2.0
PyOpenGL                      3.1.6
pyparsing                     3.0.9
pyrsistent                    0.19.3
PySocks                       1.7.1
pytensor                      2.10.1
pytest                        7.2.2
python-apt                    0.0.0
python-dateutil               2.8.2
python-louvain                0.16
python-slugify                8.0.1
python-utils                  3.5.2
pytz                          2022.7.1
pytz-deprecation-shim         0.1.0.post0
pyviz-comms                   2.2.1
PyWavelets                    1.4.1
PyYAML                        6.0
pyzmq                         23.2.1
qdldl                         0.1.7
qudida                        0.0.4
regex                         2022.10.31
requests                      2.27.1
requests-oauthlib             1.3.1
requests-unixsocket           0.2.0
rich                          13.3.4
rpy2                          3.5.5
rsa                           4.9
scikit-image                  0.19.3
scikit-learn                  1.2.2
scipy                         1.10.1
scs                           3.2.3
seaborn                       0.12.2
Send2Trash                    1.8.0
setuptools                    67.7.2
shapely                       2.0.1
six                           1.16.0
sklearn-pandas                2.2.0
smart-open                    6.3.0
sniffio                       1.3.0
snowballstemmer               2.2.0
sortedcontainers              2.4.0
soundfile                     0.12.1
soupsieve                     2.4.1
soxr                          0.3.5
spacy                         3.5.2
spacy-legacy                  3.0.12
spacy-loggers                 1.0.4
Sphinx                        3.5.4
sphinxcontrib-applehelp       1.0.4
sphinxcontrib-devhelp         1.0.2
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp        2.0.1
sphinxcontrib-jsmath          1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp          1.0.3
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5
SQLAlchemy                    2.0.10
sqlparse                      0.4.4
srsly                         2.4.6
statsmodels                   0.13.5
sympy                         1.11.1
tables                        3.8.0
tabulate                      0.8.10
tblib                         1.7.0
tenacity                      8.2.2
tensorboard                   2.12.2
tensorboard-data-server       0.7.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit        1.8.1
tensorflow                    2.12.0
tensorflow-datasets           4.8.3
tensorflow-estimator          2.12.0
tensorflow-gcs-config         2.12.0
tensorflow-hub                0.13.0
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem  0.32.0
tensorflow-metadata           1.13.1
tensorflow-probability        0.19.0
tensorstore                   0.1.36
termcolor                     2.3.0
terminado                     0.17.1
text-unidecode                1.3
textblob                      0.17.1
tf-slim                       1.1.0
thinc                         8.1.9
threadpoolctl                 3.1.0
tifffile                      2023.4.12
tinycss2                      1.2.1
toml                          0.10.2
tomli                         2.0.1
toolz                         0.12.0
torch                         2.0.0+cu118
torchaudio                    2.0.1+cu118
torchdata                     0.6.0
torchsummary                  1.5.1
torchtext                     0.15.1
torchvision                   0.15.1+cu118
tornado                       6.2
tqdm                          4.65.0
traitlets                     5.7.1
triton                        2.0.0
tweepy                        4.13.0
typer                         0.7.0
typing_extensions             4.5.0
tzdata                        2023.3
tzlocal                       4.3
uritemplate                   4.1.1
urllib3                       1.26.15
vega-datasets                 0.9.0
wasabi                        1.1.1
wcwidth                       0.2.6
webcolors                     1.13
webencodings                  0.5.1
websocket-client              1.5.1
Werkzeug                      2.3.0
wheel                         0.40.0
widgetsnbextension            3.6.4
wordcloud                     1.8.2.2
wrapt                         1.14.1
xarray                        2022.12.0
xarray-einstats               0.5.1
xgboost                       1.7.5
xlrd                          2.0.1
yellowbrick                   1.5
yfinance                      0.2.18
zict                          3.0.0
zipp                          3.15.0
```

I have tried to restart runtime with deleting all dependencies, tried to start this cell in new notebook, tried to import mapping
`from collections.abc import Mapping`
nothing works for me, i don't even understand reason for this change in my project. Hope anybody will help me, thanks!

Comment: Google Colab broke a lot of stuff by updating Python version they have, see [here](https://medium.com/google-colab/colab-updated-to-python-3-10-27eb02daa162). Until mid-May there is a way to go back to Python 3.9. Looks like the 3.8.0 version of gensim needs updating to work with Python 3.10. You could possibly edit it [the way spelled out here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69727802/8508004). Might not be the only issue though. Or specify a newer version than 3.8.0 of `gensim`; it looks like that issue was addressed [according to here](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/pull/2750).

Answer (score 0):

The code runs fine under Colab with `Python=3.10` when ignoring **the unsuported Mallet wrapper**, removed in`gensim=4.*` [due to maintenance difficulties](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/wiki/Migrating-from-Gensim-3.x-to-4#15-removed-third-party-wrappers). My advice would be to not sacrifice modern Python and modern gensim for this wrapper.

```py
from collections.abc import Mapping
import gensim
import gensim.corpora as corpora
from gensim.utils import simple_preprocess
#from gensim.models.wrappers import LdaMallet
from gensim.models.coherencemodel import CoherenceModel
from gensim import similarities
import pandas as pd
import os.path
import re
import glob
```

**What do you really lose**? Mallet's vs gensim's implementations can be roughly compared as the [accuracy-speed tradeoff due to different algorithms](https://groups.google.com/g/gensim/c/_VO4otCV6cU), namely Gibbs sampling vs Variational Bayes. Unless your use-case is to have very high accuracy (for academic projects or so) or to maintain the legacy code (not recommended due to stopped maintenance), you should be fine with gensim implementation.