# Import error when trying to run discord bot

Tags: python

I am trying to run my discord bot through IDLE 3.11 and have installed all necessary libraries through PyPI. However, I am encountering an issue when trying to run it. The full error stack is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\python projects\newer Vorpal\main.py", line 4, in <module>
from game import game, shopping
  File "E:\python projects\newer Vorpal\game.py", line 10, in <module>
from monsters import createmonsters
  File "E:\python projects\newer Vorpal\monsters.py", line 2, in <module>
import requests
  File "C:\Users\andreas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\andreas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Users\andreas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 29, in <module>
from .connection import (
  File "C:\Users\andreas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 39, in <module>
from .util.ssl_ import (
  File "C:\Users\andreas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from .connection import is_connection_dropped
  File "C:\Users\andreas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 3, in <module>
from .wait import wait_for_read
  File "C:\Users\andreas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\wait.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .selectors import (
  File "C:\Users\andreas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\selectors.py", line 14, in <module>
  from collections import namedtuple, Mapping
ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Users\andreas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\collections\__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 1):

try changing:
`from collections import Mapping`
to:
`from collections.abc import Mapping`

found in another post

[in VS Code ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69381312/in-vs-code-importerror-cannot-import-name-mapping-from-collections)