# PIP Traceback Error Installing PyInstall Library

Tags: python, pip, pyinstaller

Today i was creating a code in python, i tried to install the pyinstall library with the command:
`pip install pyinstaller`
I Recieved the next error
`Traceback (most recent call last): File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code File "C:\Users\JUAN ANDRES TELLEZ V\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 16, in <module> from pip._internal import main as _main  # isort:skip # noqa ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ File "C:\Users\JUAN ANDRES TELLEZ V\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\__init__.py", line 40, in <module> from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete File "C:\Users\JUAN ANDRES TELLEZ V\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 8, in <module> from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser File "C:\Users\JUAN ANDRES TELLEZ V\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 12, in <module> from pip._internal.commands import ( File "C:\Users\JUAN ANDRES TELLEZ V\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\__init__.py", line 6, in <module> from pip._internal.commands.completion import CompletionCommand File "C:\Users\JUAN ANDRES TELLEZ V\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\completion.py", line 6, in <module> from pip._internal.cli.base_command import Command File "C:\Users\JUAN ANDRES TELLEZ V\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 23, in <module> from pip._internal.index import PackageFinder File "C:\Users\JUAN ANDRES TELLEZ V\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_internal\index.py", line 14, in <module> from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests, six File "C:\Users\JUAN ANDRES TELLEZ V\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\__init__.py", line 25, in <module> from .html5parser import HTMLParser, parse, parseFragment File "C:\Users\JUAN ANDRES TELLEZ V\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\html5parser.py", line 8, in <module> from . import _tokenizer File "C:\Users\JUAN ANDRES TELLEZ V\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\_tokenizer.py", line 16, in <module> from ._trie import Trie File "C:\Users\JUAN ANDRES TELLEZ V\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\_trie\__init__.py", line 3, in <module> from .py import Trie as PyTrie File "C:\Users\JUAN ANDRES TELLEZ V\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\_trie\py.py", line 6, in <module> from ._base import Trie as ABCTrie File "C:\Users\JUAN ANDRES TELLEZ V\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\_trie\_base.py", line 3, in <module> from collections import Mapping ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections' (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\collections\__init__.py)`

I Tried to reinstall python, I expected that the command work, but the error was the same
I'm using Python 3.11.3 and already added python to path
Thanks for reading

Comment: Hi there, if you look towards the bottom of the error log it looks like a problem with the collections module: `line 3, in <module> from collections import Mapping ImportError: cannot import name 'Mapping' from 'collections'`. This post mentions a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69381312/in-vs-code-importerror-cannot-import-name-mapping-from-collections

let me know if it helps!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+ImportError+%22cannot+import+name+Mapping+from+collections%22

Comment: Edit file `C:\Users\JUAN ANDRES TELLEZ V\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pip\_vendor\html5lib\_trie\_base.py`