# Error uploading data to the DataStore in CKAN

Tags: file-upload, datastore, ckan

I installed CKAN version 2.10 using package install and also installed the DataStore. According to the documentation, the DataPusher is already included in the installation, and it just needs configuration.

After installing the DataStore, I tested it with a curl request, and it returned "success:true," so I assume it's installed correctly.

Then, I configured the DataPusher as follows:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ps2Pm.png)

However, when trying to upload a CSV file to the DataStore in order to create data visualizations through charts and tables, I always encounter the following error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOncr.png)

I would appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue.

I tried to verify if the configuration was done correctly, and it seems to be so.
Then, I attempted to search for the error, but unfortunately, very few options appeared.

I found something related to the Python version, suggesting that I needed to make this change:
From:
from collections import Mapping
To:
from collections.abc import Mapping
However, this change did not work either.

I also tried seeking help from people who have worked with CKAN, and I received the following response: 'Overall, we have the idea that this is not a very reliable extension.'

Answer (score 0):

i'd recommend following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/70557518/465064

this change  `from collections import Mapping -> from collections.abc import Mapping` refers to a change intruduced in python 3.10 i i'd suggest you simply try to run this on python 3.9.

In the CKAN documentation you have:

> These are just some quick notes on getting CKAN 2.10 up and
> running on Ubuntu 22.04
>
> Ubuntu 22.04 comes with Python 3.10 installed. **Python 3.10 seems to be**
> **causing problems when installing CKAN (Beaker, distutils module) so**
> **the quickest solution is to install Python 3.9 which seems to work OK**

https://github.com/ckan/ckan/wiki/CKAN-2.10-(aka-master-@1-Dec-2022)-install-on-Ubuntu-22.04#ckan-210-install-notes-for-ubuntu-2204